# Out of memory at Eclipse startup - Oomph Setup UI seems at fault - heap increased to 4G already

Tags: java, eclipse, out-of-memory, oomph

Eclipse Neon was freshly unzipped. A blank directory was given to it for workspace. And an Out of memory error gets displayed right after the workspace path query. The details mention "Setup Check".

In eclipse.ini we now have

```
-Xms1024m
-Xmx4096m
```

But this does not resolve the issue.

Then we tried to disable plugins through Preferences>General>Startup. It seems that disabling Oomph Setup UI causes the OOM to go away.

I am honestly not sure what Oomph does. The environment is for modifying and building a Java/Maven project that is stored in Github (EGit is to be installed). So I wonder if things will bemuch worse without this plugin. But more importantly might there be a way to fix this? It does not happen on other machines...

IBM JDK 1.8 is used.

Comment: Oomph allows the automation of Eclipse installation and configuration. If you don't know it, you probably don't need it. I'm sorry I can't help you with the OOM caused. Maybe you hit a bug that you could report at https://bugs.eclipse.org/.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be caused by a bug in the latest Java JDK, as stated here: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1089375/